# Exception in ASGI application when connecting to Supabase

Tags: python, fastapi, supabase

In my code, I have created a supabase client, put the keys and URL in a .env file and made a client as shown

```
from dotenv import load_dotenv
from supabase import create_client, Client

import os


load_dotenv()

url: str = os.getenv("SUPABASE_PROJECT_URL")
key: str = os.getenv("SUPABASE_PUBLIC_API_KEY")
callback_url = os.getenv("CALLBACK_URL")

supabase: Client = create_client(url, key)
```

when I made a login or a get request (get request code shown below)

```
@app.get("/cdms")
async def get_all_cdms(page: str | None = None):
    
    if not page: 
        all_cdms = cdms.get_all_cdms()
        return {"cdms": all_cdms}
    else:
        print(int(page))
        to_item = int(page)*10
        
        # only return 10 results per page. hence -10
        from_item = to_item - 10

        
        select_cdms = cdms.get_cdm_in_range(from_item, to_item)
        return {"from": from_item, "to": to_item, "cdms": select_cdms}

def get_all_cdms():
    return supabase.table(TABLE_NAME).select("*").execute()
```

When I run this in postman or my URL, I get an internal server error. Looking more into it, the terminal returns this

```
ERROR:    Exception in ASGI application
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/nnagelia/.pyenv/versions/3.11.3/lib/python3.11/site-packages/httpcore/_exceptions.py", line 10, in map_exceptions
    yield
  File "/Users/nnagelia/.pyenv/versions/3.11.3/lib/python3.11/site-packages/httpcore/_backends/sync.py", line 100, in connect_tcp
    sock = socket.create_connection(
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/Users/nnagelia/.pyenv/versions/3.11.3/lib/python3.11/socket.py", line 827, in create_connection
    for res in getaddrinfo(host, port, 0, SOCK_STREAM):
               ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/Users/nnagelia/.pyenv/versions/3.11.3/lib/python3.11/socket.py", line 962, in getaddrinfo
    for res in _socket.getaddrinfo(host, port, family, type, proto, flags):
               ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
socket.gaierror: [Errno 8] nodename nor servname provided, or not known

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/nnagelia/.pyenv/versions/3.11.3/lib/python3.11/site-packages/httpx/_transports/default.py", line 60, in map_httpcore_exceptions
    yield
  File "/Users/nnagelia/.pyenv/versions/3.11.3/lib/python3.11/site-packages/httpx/_transports/default.py", line 218, in handle_request
    resp = self._pool.handle_request(req)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/Users/nnagelia/.pyenv/versions/3.11.3/lib/python3.11/site-packages/httpcore/_sync/connection_pool.py", line 262, in handle_request
    raise exc
  File "/Users/nnagelia/.pyenv/versions/3.11.3/lib/python3.11/site-packages/httpcore/_sync/connection_pool.py", line 245, in handle_request
    response = connection.handle_request(request)
               ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/Users/nnagelia/.pyenv/versions/3.11.3/lib/python3.11/site-packages/httpcore/_sync/connection.py", line 92, in handle_request
    raise exc
  File "/Users/nnagelia/.pyenv/versions/3.11.3/lib/python3.11/site-packages/httpcore/_sync/connection.py", line 69, in handle_request
    stream = self._connect(request)
             ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/Users/nnagelia/.pyenv/versions/3.11.3/lib/python3.11/site-packages/httpcore/_sync/connection.py", line 117, in _connect
    stream = self._network_backend.connect_tcp(**kwargs)
             ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/Users/nnagelia/.pyenv/versions/3.11.3/lib/python3.11/site-packages/httpcore/_backends/sync.py", line 99, in connect_tcp
    with map_exceptions(exc_map):
  File "/Users/nnagelia/.pyenv/versions/3.11.3/lib/python3.11/contextlib.py", line 155, in __exit__
    self.gen.throw(typ, value, traceback)
  File "/Users/nnagelia/.pyenv/versions/3.11.3/lib/python3.11/site-packages/httpcore/_exceptions.py", line 14, in map_exceptions
    raise to_exc(exc) from exc
httpcore.ConnectError: [Errno 8] nodename nor servname provided, or not known

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/nnagelia/.pyenv/versions/3.11.3/lib/python3.11/site-packages/uvicorn/protocols/http/h11_impl.py", line 412, in run_asgi
    result = await app(  # type: ignore[func-returns-value]
             ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/Users/nnagelia/.pyenv/versions/3.11.3/lib/python3.11/site-packages/uvicorn/middleware/proxy_headers.py", line 84, in __call__
    return await self.app(scope, receive, send)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/Users/nnagelia/.pyenv/versions/3.11.3/lib/python3.11/site-packages/fastapi/applications.py", line 1054, in __call__
    await super().__call__(scope, receive, send)
  File "/Users/nnagelia/.pyenv/versions/3.11.3/lib/python3.11/site-packages/starlette/applications.py", line 123, in __call__
    await self.middleware_stack(scope, receive, send)
  File "/Users/nnagelia/.pyenv/versions/3.11.3/lib/python3.11/site-packages/starlette/middleware/errors.py", line 186, in __call__
    raise exc
  File "/Users/nnagelia/.pyenv/versions/3.11.3/lib/python3.11/site-packages/starlette/middleware/errors.py", line 164, in __call__
    await self.app(scope, receive, _send)
  File "/Users/nnagelia/.pyenv/versions/3.11.3/lib/python3.11/site-packages/starlette/middleware/exceptions.py", line 62, in __call__
    await wrap_app_handling_exceptions(self.app, conn)(scope, receive, send)
  File "/Users/nnagelia/.pyenv/versions/3.11.3/lib/python3.11/site-packages/starlette/_exception_handler.py", line 64, in wrapped_app
    raise exc
  File "/Users/nnagelia/.pyenv/versions/3.11.3/lib/python3.11/site-packages/starlette/_exception_handler.py", line 53, in wrapped_app
    await app(scope, receive, sender)
  File "/Users/nnagelia/.pyenv/versions/3.11.3/lib/python3.11/site-packages/starlette/routing.py", line 758, in __call__
    await self.middleware_stack(scope, receive, send)
  File "/Users/nnagelia/.pyenv/versions/3.11.3/lib/python3.11/site-packages/starlette/routing.py", line 778, in app
    await route.handle(scope, receive, send)
  File "/Users/nnagelia/.pyenv/versions/3.11.3/lib/python3.11/site-packages/starlette/routing.py", line 299, in handle
    await self.app(scope, receive, send)
  File "/Users/nnagelia/.pyenv/versions/3.11.3/lib/python3.11/site-packages/starlette/routing.py", line 79, in app
    await wrap_app_handling_exceptions(app, request)(scope, receive, send)
  File "/Users/nnagelia/.pyenv/versions/3.11.3/lib/python3.11/site-packages/starlette/_exception_handler.py", line 64, in wrapped_app
    raise exc
  File "/Users/nnagelia/.pyenv/versions/3.11.3/lib/python3.11/site-packages/starlette/_exception_handler.py", line 53, in wrapped_app
    await app(scope, receive, sender)
  File "/Users/nnagelia/.pyenv/versions/3.11.3/lib/python3.11/site-packages/starlette/routing.py", line 74, in app
    response = await func(request)
               ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/Users/nnagelia/.pyenv/versions/3.11.3/lib/python3.11/site-packages/fastapi/routing.py", line 299, in app
    raise e
  File "/Users/nnagelia/.pyenv/versions/3.11.3/lib/python3.11/site-packages/fastapi/routing.py", line 294, in app
    raw_response = await run_endpoint_function(
                   ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/Users/nnagelia/.pyenv/versions/3.11.3/lib/python3.11/site-packages/fastapi/routing.py", line 191, in run_endpoint_function
    return await dependant.call(**values)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/Users/nnagelia/Documents/AmazonKuiper/space-ledger-backend/main.py", line 59, in get_all_cdms
    select_cdms = cdms.get_cdm_in_range(from_item, to_item)
                  ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/Users/nnagelia/Documents/AmazonKuiper/space-ledger-backend/cdms/cdms.py", line 52, in get_cdm_in_range
    return supabase.table(TABLE_NAME).select("*").range(start, end).execute()
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/Users/nnagelia/.pyenv/versions/3.11.3/lib/python3.11/site-packages/postgrest/_sync/request_builder.py", line 57, in execute
    r = self.session.request(
        ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/Users/nnagelia/.pyenv/versions/3.11.3/lib/python3.11/site-packages/httpx/_client.py", line 814, in request
    return self.send(request, auth=auth, follow_redirects=follow_redirects)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/Users/nnagelia/.pyenv/versions/3.11.3/lib/python3.11/site-packages/httpx/_client.py", line 901, in send
    response = self._send_handling_auth(
               ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/Users/nnagelia/.pyenv/versions/3.11.3/lib/python3.11/site-packages/httpx/_client.py", line 929, in _send_handling_auth
    response = self._send_handling_redirects(
               ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/Users/nnagelia/.pyenv/versions/3.11.3/lib/python3.11/site-packages/httpx/_client.py", line 966, in _send_handling_redirects
    response = self._send_single_request(request)
               ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/Users/nnagelia/.pyenv/versions/3.11.3/lib/python3.11/site-packages/httpx/_client.py", line 1002, in _send_single_request
    response = transport.handle_request(request)
               ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/Users/nnagelia/.pyenv/versions/3.11.3/lib/python3.11/site-packages/httpx/_transports/default.py", line 217, in handle_request
    with map_httpcore_exceptions():
  File "/Users/nnagelia/.pyenv/versions/3.11.3/lib/python3.11/contextlib.py", line 155, in __exit__
    self.gen.throw(typ, value, traceback)
  File "/Users/nnagelia/.pyenv/versions/3.11.3/lib/python3.11/site-packages/httpx/_transports/default.py", line 77, in map_httpcore_exceptions
    raise mapped_exc(message) from exc
httpx.ConnectError: [Errno 8] nodename nor servname provided, or not known
```

I am unsure how to fix this, please help me solve this

Answer (score 1):

The error message you're hitting

```
socket.gaierror: [Errno 8] nodename nor servname provided, or not known
```

is saying that DNS is not resolving the URL to an IP address.

The most likely culprit is a hostname typo in your .env file. To debug that try printing your `url` variable and confirm it's what you expect. It should be in the form:

```
https://afcvmsjdzstabszjjtbv.supabase.co
```

where afcvmsjdzstabszjjtbv would be your project ref

A couple of other possibilities if that isn't the issue:

- If you created the project very recently it might not have propagated yet, in which case the problem will likely go away after a few minutes.
- If you're overriding domain names in your local hosts file, an incorrect entry could lead to this error.